# Does it matter that some threads of the block reach __syncthreads() and some of them not?

Tags: c++, cuda, synchronization

The question is simple, does it matter that some threads of the block reach `__syncthreads()` and some of them not? Take the following code.

```
for (unsigned int s=blockDim.x/2; s>0; s>>=1) {
    if (tid < s) {
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
    } else {
       break;
    }
    __syncthreads();
}
```

Does it make some deadlock or some other issues? Should I put `__syncthreads()` after for or is it good like this?

Comment: `__syncthreads()` must be called in every thread. You must not call it conditional on some variable data like you do here. (I believe this is [well documented](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions).)

Comment: I'll check the whole documentation, however I used it in my code and everything went well and the algorithm was faster too.

Comment: Please never ever get a professional job writing software with that attitude, and especially stay away from banking, defense and playground software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **undefined behavior**:

> __syncthreads() is allowed in conditional code but only if the conditional evaluates identically across the entire thread block,
>   otherwise the code execution is likely to hang or produce unintended
>   side effects.

Read more at: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html